# Strange bevel and union behvaior

Tags: modifiers, bevel

I was trying to follow this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C3n3DFxYm_Y) to increase my understanding of bevels.

I got to 19:36 when I noticed that my cylinder can only go so far towards the edge, until it starts acting strangely. Is there a way I can fix this?

[image]

### Further from edge

[image]

### Closer to edge

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Disabling loop slide on the last bevel modifier seemed to do the trick, it doesn't look very smooth though so if anyone has a better answer please post it